# How to create a UITabBarController and connect its tabs with coordinators?

Tags: ios, swift

I've recently been inspired to learn MVVM-C (C for Coordinators) and I'm now trying to rewrite my current project to use it, but I'm struggling to figure out how to create a tab bar controller, where each tab has it's own coordinator.

I have a `LoginCoordinator` that, once the user logs in, creates a `TabCoordinator` that *should* create 3 coordinators, each coordinating a tab.

The most obvious solution would be to have the coordinator's `start()` functions to return the view controllers that they create, so I guess it would look kinda like this:

```
class TabCoordinator {
  func start() {
    let fooCoordinator = FooCoordinator(...)
    let fooVC = fooCoordinator.start()

    // create other coordinators/VCs

    tabBarController.viewControllers = [fooVC, ...]
  }
}


class FooCoordinator {
  func start() -> UIViewController {
    let fooVC = FooViewController(...)
    // ...
    return fooVC
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or if there's a better way, but having the `start()` functions return something feels wrong somehow...

Comment: Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I feel that it is usually the job of the parent coordinator to present a child coordinator's controller so my `start()` function is `func start(presentationHander: @escaping (UIViewController) -> ())`. The `start()` function for your `TabCoordinator` would look something like this:

```
class TabCoordinator : Coordinator {
    func start(presentationHander: @escaping (UIViewController) -> ()) {
        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
        var tabBarControllers = [UIViewController]()

        let fooCoordinator = FooCoordinator()
        fooCoordinator.start { (controller) in
            tabBarControllers.append(controller)
        }

        tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarControllers
        presentationHander(tabBarController)
    }
}

class FooCoordinator : Coordinator {
    func start(presentationHander: @escaping (UIViewController) -> ()) {
        let fooVC = FooViewController.makeFromStoryboard()
        presentationHander(settingVC)
    }    
}
```

FooCoordinator is responsible for initializing its own dependencies but allows TabCoordinator to present its controller.

I find this gives me more flexibility when reusing controllers. The parent coordinator can choose to present as modal or push the controller onto a UINavigationController or into a UITabBarController. The child coordinator shouldn't really care about the context into which it is added.

As for `start()` returning a controller or accepting a closure or even having the coordinator expose the controller via a property I'm not sure it matters much. I chose a closure because I wanted control over exactly when during the `start()` function the controller's view would be added to the view hierarchy.